# Error when pulling from server

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am getting an error when I try to pull from my remote webserver, the error is

```
 fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This is after I run the command 
`git fetch live master` or `git pull live master`

If I run `git branch` though it does not show anything it just moves on to the next line.

Thanks

Comment: I think you've initialised an empty git repository with `git init`. If you want to copy a remote repository , you have to clone it first `git clone 'repo-name'`

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.git/config` file, in section `[branch "master"]` you must have:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = live
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

After that, just run command `git branch -a` you will see all available branches.

Comment: This is what happens if I run `git branch -a` after editing the config file http://prntscr.com/g8n1wi

Comment: Or you have error in configuration to remote repo in config file section `[remote "origin"]`.

Comment: I'm trying to copy files from my existing webserver to my new repo so then I can edit it on my computer rather than on my webserver

Comment: Do you have git on your webserver?

Comment: yes I have git setup in /var/repo/test.git then a work tree linked to /var/www/test

Comment: Reuse config from your webserver on your local machine, especially sections `remote` and `branch`.

Comment: What should be in the remote section on my webserver?

Comment: Something like: [remote "origin"]

 url = git+ssh://git@github.com/cn007b/my.git

 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to this, what does this bit mean? git+ssh://git@github.com/cn007b/my.git

Comment: It means use [tag:ssh] to push/pull data into my repo. Also it can be something like: `https://github.com/cn007b/my.git` which means use `https` for same purposes.

Comment: Would it be possible than rather to have my website publicly available on github, to just edit it on my local machine through git rather than github?

Comment: It is possible to have own git server (not github) but it is definitely must not be your local machine.

Comment: Ah right, so I guess I'll just have to resort to using github then

Comment: Just create new repo on github, clone it into your local machine, copy files from your webserver into it, commit and push. That's it.

Comment: So when I copy the files from my webserver, they're getting copied to my local machine correct?

Comment: Yes. And after commit and push into repo files will be available in repo on github.

Comment: Sorry I just want to get this 100% correct, I made an empty  repo on gitbub, cloned it to my local machine, then I need to make the remote paths to the github repo. Then do I fetch from the webserver and commit?